# Text is not justified after adding a picture

Tags: horizontal-alignment

My text was justified by its width as it should be. But after adding the picture it was its left and right borders became not right.

How can I fix it? [image]

Here is the code snippet:

```
\section{Samples}

\subsection{Schedule Application }

...First subsection text1 (see Fig.1)

\vskip 1em
\centering
    \begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=0.425\textwidth]{Schedule4.eps}

\caption{Schedule application scheme}
\label{fig_sim2}
\end{figure}

 ...First subsection text2 (see Fig.2) 

\vskip 1em
    \begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=0.425\textwidth]{ScheduleForms.eps}

\caption{Schedule application UI form}
\label{fig_sim2}
\end{figure}


\vskip 1em

\subsection{Application with authorization}

\vskip 1em

...Second subsection text1


\vskip 1em
    \begin{figure}[H]

\includegraphics[width=0.425\textwidth]{Volunteer.eps}

\caption{Application with authorization scheme}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure}

...Second subsection text2

\vskip 1em
    \begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=0.425\textwidth]{555.eps}

\caption{UbiqMobile screens}
\label{fig_sim2}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: you have put **\centering** tag in side text                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                    
`\vskip 1em
    \begin{figure}[H]
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.425\textwidth]{Schedule4.eps}
\caption{Schedule application scheme}
\label{fig_sim2}
\end{figure}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By placing the `\centering` instruction outside of the `figure` environments, you've made its scope global. Clearly, that's not what you want.

To fix this, you need to

- remove the `\centering` instruction that occurs before the first `\begin{figure}` statement, and
- if and as needed, insert new `\centering` instructions *inside* the `\figure` environments.

A separate comment: Your document appears to have a lot of visual formatting directives of the form `\vskip 1em`. Instead of pursuing such a tedious and, likely, error-prone approach, you'd be better off tweaking some global parameters. Feel free to post a new query, to illustrate what you're doing at the moment and asking for suitable tweaks to that you no longer need to concern yourself with all those visual formatting directives.